# Cannot create, update, or delete any file in github repository

Tags: github

When I try to create/edit/delete and press commit changes, it just says that file cannot be created/edited/deleted on the top part of my screen. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Show your screenshot.

Comment: Showed screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I do few tasks:

- Fork respository
- Looking for file `https://github.com/account_name/vydingding.github.io/blob/master/_data/file_name` or something like this.
- After fork, source code under my permissions. I press delete icon,
  **ENTER COMMIT MESSAGE**, then press button `Commit changes`
- File deleted success.
  [image]

[image]